# Errors in the css when checking in the validator

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web project where I use CSS custom properties (variables) to control animation delays and transformations. However, I've encountered an issue where the browser doesn't seem to recognize the default values I provided for these properties(errors in the photo below). How can I fix it?

[image: validator]

I tried to google but to no avail

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #333;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: #e76236e8;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right;
}

.social-media-icons {
  display: inline;
}

.social-media-icons a {
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.hero-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
  background-image: url('../img/main2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.hero-section h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #e76236e8;
  background-color: #1d0e0ed2;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.scroll-down-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -43px;
  margin-left: -43px;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  width: 86px;
  height: 86px;
  background: #adcb28;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: background 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scroll-down-button span {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.scroll-down-button:hover {
  background-color: #6d8000;
}

footer {
  background-color: #293353;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

footer .validation-link a {
  color: #3fda6b;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

footer .validation-link a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.second-half {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.block {
  flex-basis: 32%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  color: #e76236e8;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text-block {
  color: #e76236e8;
}

.nested-numeric ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

.nested-numeric li {
  display: block;
}

.nested-numeric li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.intro-text h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

Comment: what validator are you using?

Comment: Where are these properties int he CSS you posted?

Comment: "Errors in the css" - can you share any of them?

Comment: The default value for `animation-delay` is `0s` not `0`

Comment: @artikandri
https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Did you read my comment? [w3c output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaSsu.png)

Comment: @DarkBee so what i need to do? Write code which in screenshoot to my css ? Or What

Comment: Change every instance in your screenshot from `0` to `0s`, e.g. `var(--fa-animation-delay, 0s)`? But I'm guessing this CSS is not yours (but from FontAwesome) and you shouldn't bother with the validation